# Will galvanized hog paneling hold up vegetable and fruit vines?

Tags: vines, fence, deer

I noticed that hog panel fencing is a lot cheaper than pipe fencing, and was wondering will the hog panel fencing hold up the weight of different vegetables ranging from kiwiberry to cucumbers (maybe a small watermelon)?

How should I determine how many t-posts I need?

Comment: Can you provide the size of the panel? And how are you orienting the panel?

Comment: I'm thinking the 16' 4 gauge standard panels you can find at hardware stores.

Comment: I moved this here because it's a question about what to use to support some vining vegetables and fruits, so likely to get answers from people who grow those plants.

Comment: This is a fence construction question, not a gardening question.

Answer (score 3):

Hog panels are made of pretty heavy gauge wire. As long as the supports holding them upright are strong enough to support the weight you should be fine. The support ability of the ground is really the deciding factor.

T posts are one way to support the hog fence. You just need to find t posts long enough to make a good bite into the ground.

**Here's an example of t post hog wire fencing**[image]

https://www.google.com/amp/s/allaspectsfencing.com/t-post-support-wire-for-your-fence/amp/

I've used hog wire to make locking cages for tool storage and I can tell you it's pretty strong but it is a little floppy. If you have hanging fruit densely packed, high winds may pose a problem.

Comment: this is a copy/paste answer

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: @blackthumb What do you mean by this being a "copy/paste" answer?

Comment: @NiallC. think about the gardening site no plagiarism rule

Comment: @blackthumb if you see something that doesn’t follow the rules described [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/referencing), flag a moderator *and clearly describe the problem*, including the undisclosed source.

Comment: @blackthumb I'm very aware of the "no plagiarism" rule. If this post is plagiarized, please post a link to the original source because neither I nor Stephie were able to find one. If it's not plagiarized, then a retraction of your comments and an apology to Joe Fala is in order.